# Displaying Hashbytes value in SSRS matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a simple query that I am trying to display the hashbytes value in an SSRS matrix - This throws an error when rendering the matrix

My Query

```
    select  hashbytes('md5',Consultant_Code) as Consultant_Code, 
    hashbytes('md5',Surgeon1_Code) as Surgeon_Code
    from TheatreOps
```

When this renders in preview view it displays #Error where I expect to see the value, has anyone had this before and could maybe suggest a fix please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following

```
SELECT 
'0x' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', Consultant_Code),2) as Consultant_Code,
'0x' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', Surgeon_Code),2) as Surgeon_Code,
FROM TheatreOps
```

Answer (score 0):

SSRS handling of the returned data type (varbinary) could be the issue.

Try:

```
select  cast(hashbytes('md5',Consultant_Code) as varchar) as Consultant_Code, 
        cast(hashbytes('md5',Surgeon1_Code) as varchar) as Surgeon_Code
from TheatreOps
```

Comment: Thanks but I am expecting values like this 0x0021EA67FB5C6F30EAE9C2A95B6C196E not like this ‡ÇÆî¡v†àÌ1<mŠo - do i need to perhaps get SSRS to render the value differently or do i keep this in the SQL layer?

Comment: After a small amount of research I have found that using the function fn_varbintohexstr can resolve the problem, I now have the desired output. Syntax of this:  SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('MD5', Consultant_Code)), 3, 32)

Comment: `fn_varbintohexstr` is not a documented function as far as I know so exercise caution if you decide to go this route.

Comment: Thanks @Alan Schofield I will note your point - problem solved